# Bitbucket pipeline failing due to Eslint/prettier styling

Tags: deployment, bitbucket, eslint, prettier

I am using Eslint and Prettier to style and format my code. I have already set up my eslint and prettier configuration and everything is working fine. However, I am facing a problem on the bitbucket deployment. When my code is deployed, the pipeline fails due to eslint/prettier linting errors. However, these errors were not present when I run my code locally. It seems that the pipeline is not linting correctly?

Some advice or help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error because of a version issue with eslint. Once we incremented the version, deleted the node-modules and package.lock file, we were able to resolve the errors successfully by formatting the erroring files individually